# Visual Studio community 2017 download and install sizes in every Workload

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community

What is download and install size for every workload of visual studio community edition?
specially .Net Core and Web development workloads?

Comment: You can investigate that. Why is this relevant?

Comment: Download size is important because i am in a country with limited internet. I have to buy every gigabyte of internet and when my internet size is running out my internet will be disconnected and download will be corrupted. besides internet in my country is expensive. I know install size but i don't know download size. I need to know download size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i installed visual studio 2017 (15.5.2) with .Net Core work space and download size was about 1 GB.